# Redis init from Clojure

Tags: clojure, redis, init

I am trying to connect to a remote Redis server, but am having extreme trouble with figuring out how to set it up.  I can telnet into the Redis server perfectly fine.  From Redis-cli I can connect to the Redis server fine.

But when I setup Redis as I am below I just get:

ConnectException Connection refused java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect (PlainSocketImpl.java:-2)

```
(require clj-redis.client :as redis)
(def db (redis/init :url "redis://0.0.0.0:6379))
```

I've also tried it without the "redis://" section of the url and got the same results.

Does anyone have an idea of what is going on or things to try?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know redis specifically but the `0.0.0.0` ip address in the url looks odd. `0.0.0.0` is a [non-routable meta-address used to designate an invalid, unknown or non applicable target.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0) When opening a (server) socket for listening you'd do this to signal that the socket should be bound to all ip addresses on the machine, but as a client it doesn't make sense.

```
;If your redis server is running locally you should do 

(require clj-redis.client :as redis)
(def db (redis/init :url "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"))

; better? probably leave out the default port...

(require clj-redis.client :as redis)
(def db (redis/init :url "redis://localhost"))

;if it's remote change ``127.0.0.1`` to the correct address.
```

Answer (score 0):

i'm using [accession](https://github.com/abedra/accession)

(def c (accession.core/connection-map {})) ;; {} - default settings

and then 
(with-connection c "... redis-cmd")